# How to show the full remainder in polynomial long division?

Tags: polynom

## Original

The remainder provided by `polynom.sty` is NOT complete (as shown in the following figure).

[image]

---

## My Objective

When I was in senior high school, my teacher made the diagram like below. :-)

Thus the final step must show the TOTAL remainder and mark it with L-shaped curve.

## NOTE

I am sorry. The previous post I forgot to put back `-1/4` in the original position. It have made you confused. Now there is no mistake anymore. :-)

[image]

---

## Minimal Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\makeatletter
\def\pld@ArrangeResult#1{%
    \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty
        \@tempcnta\pld@maxcol\relax
        \pld@InsertItems@do\pld@lastline
            {\pld@firsttrue\pld@PLD{\pld@R{0}{1}}}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\pld@currstage>\z@
        \pld@Extend\pld@allines{\pld@lastline\cr}%
    \else
        \pld@InsertFake\pld@lastline
    \fi
    \pld@iftopresult
        \def\pld@lastline{\pld@PrintPoly\pld@divisor%
        %====================================================================================
        \quad\smash{{\color{red}\rule[-6pt]{\arrayrulewidth}{17pt}}}\kern-\arrayrulewidth&}%
        %====================================================================================
    \else
        \let\pld@lastline\@empty
        \ifx B\pld@style\else
            \def\pld@lastline{\pld@leftdelim\strut\pld@rightxdelim&}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@PLD
                           \expandafter\pld@lastline#1+\relax+%
    \pld@SplitQuotient
    \pld@iftopresult
        \let\pld@currentline\@empty
        \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@PLD
                               \expandafter\pld@currentline
                                           \pld@quotient+\relax+%
        \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@XPLD
                               \expandafter\pld@currentline
                                           \pld@shadow+\relax+%
        \edef\pld@subline{%
            \noexpand\cline{\tw@-\pld@maxcol}%
            \noalign{\vskip\jot}}%
        \pld@Extend\pld@currentline{\expandafter\cr\pld@subline}%
    \else
        \@tempcnta-\@tempcnta
        \advance\@tempcnta\pld@maxcol\relax \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
        \edef\pld@span{\the\@tempcnta}%
        \ifx B\pld@style
          \pld@AddTo\pld@lastline{%
            &\multispan\pld@span${}=%
            \pld@PrintPolyWithDelims\pld@divisor
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@divisor}{}{\cdot}%
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@quotient}\pld@true
                                                             \pld@false
            \pld@if \pld@leftdelim
                    \pld@PrintPolyShadow
                    \pld@rightdelim
              \else \pld@PrintPolyShadow \fi
            \pld@firstfalse
            \expandafter\pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}$}%
        \else
          \pld@AddTo\pld@lastline{%
            &\multispan\pld@span$\pld@leftxdelim\strut\pld@rightdelim
            \pld@div
            \pld@PrintPolyWithDelims\pld@divisor=
            \pld@PrintPolyShadow
            \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty\else
                +{}%
                \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\displaystyle
                  \frac{\let\strut\@empty\pld@firsttrue \expandafter
                        \pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}}%
                       {\let\strut\@empty\pld@PrintPoly\pld@divisor}$}%
                \dp\z@=\z@\box\z@
            \fi
            $}%
        \fi
    \fi
\expandafter\pld@AR@\pld@allines\relax}
\makeatother


\arrayrulecolor{red}
\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt
\def\strut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{12pt}}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{\frac{3}{7}x^9+x^2-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{9}{5}x^4-1}

\vspace{1cm}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{x^4-1}{x^2-1}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: @Herbert + @Ulrike: Please see my updated figure (second figure). When I was in senior high school, my teacher made the diagram like that. :-) He stopped the operation until showing the total remainder.

Comment: I guess you don't want to _move_ the 1/4 down, but you want to _copy_ it. After all, you want to divide `\frac{3}{7}x^9+x^2-\frac{1}{4}` (_including_ the 1/4) by `\frac{9}{5}x^4-1`.

Comment: I've told you before that it's not necessary to write the whole question in the _title_ of the question `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: You are correct. I have to say "copy" instead of "drop". And I did NOT realize that delete `-1/4` from the original position. That was my big mistake and my teacher did NOT teach like that. I am thinking to shrink my title. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code should work; I've included a few test cases. To keep the code shorter, I didn't include your changes to the style of the output (red color, and bar between dividend and divisor instead of parenthesis). My changes and additions to `polynom` are marked with `!!!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,array}

\makeatletter
\def\pld@DivPoly@l{%
    \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty\else
        \pld@IfNeedsDivision\pld@remainder\pld@divisor
        {\pld@ExtendPoly\pld@quotient\pld@factor
         \pld@NMultiplyPoly\pld@sub\pld@divisor\pld@factor
         \pld@SubtractPoly\pld@remainder\pld@sub
         \expandafter\pld@DivPoly@l}%
        {\expandafter\pld@insert@remainder                       % !!!
         \pld@last@remainder+\relax\relax}                       % !!!
    \fi}
\def\pld@insert@remainder#1+#2\relax{%                           % !!!
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\else\pld@InsertItems\@empty\@empty{#1}\fi % !!!
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\pld@insert@remainder#2\relax\fi}     % !!!
\def\pld@SubtractPoly@l#1+#2\@empty#3+#4\@empty{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
        \let\pld@last@remainder\@empty                           % !!!
        \ifx\relax#3\relax \let\pld@next\@empty \else
          \pld@AddToPoly\pld@tempoly{#3}%
          \pld@if \pld@InsertItems{#3}{#3}{}\fi
          \def\pld@next{\pld@SubtractPoly@l\relax+\@empty#4\@empty}%
        \fi
    \else
    \ifx\relax#3\relax
        \pld@SubtractPoly@r#1+#2\@empty
        \let\pld@next\@empty
    \else
        \pld@IfMonomE{#1}{#3}%
        {\def\pld@temp{#1+#3}%
         \pld@CondenseMonomials\pld@true\pld@temp
         \ifx\pld@temp\@empty\else
             \pld@ExtendPoly\pld@tempoly\pld@temp
         \fi
         \pld@if \expandafter\pld@InsertItems\expandafter
                 {\pld@temp}{#3}{#1}\fi
         \def\pld@next{\pld@SubtractPoly@l#2\@empty#4\@empty}}%
        {\pld@IfMonomL{#1}{#3}%
         {\pld@AddToPoly\pld@tempoly{#3}%
          \pld@if \pld@InsertItems{#3}{#3}{}\fi
          \def\pld@next{\pld@SubtractPoly@l#1+#2\@empty#4\@empty}}%
         {\pld@AddToPoly\pld@tempoly{#1}%
          \pld@if \pld@InsertItems{#1}{}{#1}\fi
          \def\pld@next{\pld@SubtractPoly@l#2\@empty#3+#4\@empty}}%
        }%
    \fi \fi
    \pld@next}
\def\pld@SubtractPoly@r#1+\relax+\@empty{%
    \pld@AddToPoly\pld@tempoly{#1}%
    \def\pld@last@remainder{#1}}                                 % !!!
\makeatother
\def\strut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{12pt}}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{x^5-1}{x-1}

\polylongdiv{x^5-x^2}{x^2-1}

\polylongdiv{\frac{3}{7}x^9+x^2-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{9}{5}x^4-1}

\polylongdiv{x^9+x^2-1}{x^4-x}

\polylongdiv{x^{15}+1}{x^5+x^3+x+1}

\polylongdiv{x^4-1}{x^2-1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done!!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am really satisfied with it. The bounty will be given several hours later because the time barrier must be elapsed for 24 hours since the bounty is initiated.

Answer (score 3):

Well the 1/4 is not the remainder, it is the last part of the first argument. The line you are trying to change is the line which shows both polynomials. You can see this if you use a bit simpler arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt
\def\strut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{12pt}}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{x^3-1}{x^2+1}

\bigskip

\polylongdiv[style=B]{x^3-1}{x^2+1}

\bigskip

\polylongdiv[style=C]{x^3-1}{x^2+1}

\end{document}
```

Edit: The good news are that the remainder is accessible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt
\def\strut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{12pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\polylongdiv[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\pld@stage\maxdimen \polyset{#1}%
    \pld@GetPoly{\pld@polya\pld@polyb}%
                {\pld@LongDividePoly\pld@polya\pld@polyb
                 \pld@PrintLongDiv\\                   
   $\expandafter\pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}$%new
    \endgroup \ignorespaces}}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=A,stage=5]{x^3-1}{x^2+1}

\bigskip

\polylongdiv[style=A]{\frac{3}{7}x^9+x^2-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{9}{5}x^4-1}
\end{document}
```

But I don't have the time to find out how to insert it correctly in the array.

Comment: @Ulrike: Using your example, the remainder is `-x-1`. But `style=A` only produces the remainder = `-x`.

Comment: @Ulrike: `-1/4` in my example is the last term of the remainder. :-)

Comment: @Herbert: In mathematics, the remainder of `x^3-1` divided by `x^2+1` is `-x-1`. The polynom should drop `-1` to make a final remainder.

Comment: @Herbert: My final remainder is not  `-1/4` only. But `-1/4` is the last term of the remainder. If you see the updated figure (second figure), it is the final diagram when doing this calculation.

Comment: @Herbert + @Ulrike: The polynom.sty does NOT do wrong calculation but I need a modification such that at the final step the diagram show the total remainder as what many students used. The polynom.sty diagram looks unfamiliar for some students because it stops the operation without showing the final remainder.

Comment: @Herbert: OK. How to visualize the final diagram as shown in the second figure is the problem we are talking. :-)

Comment: Sorry your diagram is illogical. The x^2 and the 25/189x in the last line have been copied from the line above but the -1/4 is coming out of the blue. While I do understand that you want a final "sum" of the remainder parts it is wrong to delete the -1/4 from the starting polynomial.

Comment: @Ulrike: I forgot to put back the `-1/4` and I did realize it. :-) Sorry. Now see the updated figure. It is what my teacher explained.

Comment: @Herbert: Please see my updated figure. I forgot to put back the `-1/4` when doing image manipulation. Sorry. It might be the source of confusion.