# I think I found a bug at `polynom.sty` or my calculation is wrong

Tags: packages, polynom

When I wrote

```
\polylongdiv[style=A]{x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1}{x^2+x+1}
```

I get that there is no reminder.... but the reminder is 1 if I'm right....

I hope is OK to post things like that here...

Thank you.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8580 for a workaround